# Need help identifying a 90's sci fi cartoon

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

Here is what I remember:

It was a 90's (I think, not 100% sure, but it's very likely) cartoon series with a rather serious, non-goofy tone about a squad that dealt with paranormal / extraterrestrial activity.

They used a helicopter similar to a Chinook for transportation.

I distinctly remember one episode where a cloud formed over a small town and its rainwater made everyone sick. When the squad made it high up and into the cloud they encountered Octabrain-like creatures that acted as the cloud's bio defense mechanism. I remember those things ate live missiles that were launched at them.

I'm afraid that's pretty much all I remember, aside from the end credits theme being dark and moody.

Hope it rings a bell.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image: Bureau of Alien Detectors - Pic 01]

[**Bureau of Alien Detectors**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0123342/)

From the show's [tvtropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/BureauOfAlienDetectors) page:

> Bureau of Alien Detectors, or B.A.D., was a 1996 animated series.
>
> In it, aliens have invaded the earth. A carefully selected and
>   **trained group of five people** called the Phalanx Squad, **monitor, control, and battle the alien visitors**.
>
> But some people in the Bureau may have hidden agendas of their own
>   concerning what to do with the aliens.

Some members of the team:

[image: Bureau of Alien Detectors - Pic 02]

Here's their transport vehicle from the first episode:

[image: Bureau of Alien Detectors - Pic 03]

The episode you remember is ["**And Then Comes the Rain**"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0927770/).